# VNIC not attaching to instance when nodes and pods in different subnets

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to create a k8s cluster in oracle oci with VCN-native pod networking. I have separate subnets for my pods and nodes [(followed example 4 here)](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Concepts/contengnetworkconfigexample.htm#example-oci-cni-privatek8sapi_privateworkers_publiclb) and when oci tries to attach the secondary VNIC to the instance, it fails and the status never gets past "Attaching". However when I use the same subnet for both pods and nodes it attaches successfully. Anyone know what's going on?